# how to create column of cell-by-cell sums in excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have a spreadsheet that is extremely long and I would like to create a new column (actually, 8) where each cell in the new column is the sum of two cells in other columns.  An obvious answer is to create the column, create an instance of the formula in the first cell, and drag the formula down.  However, since the spreadsheet is so long and I would like to do this 8 times, that process does not make sense for me.  Is there an automated way to do this?  I have never worked with VBA but have enough programming experience that I figure I could figure it out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What I do, E.g. long data in columns `A` & `B`

1. Put formula in `C1` & `D1`
2. Click in `B1`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down-arrow</kbd> to go to the last cell, go over to `C` & `D` & type in any value
3. Click `C1`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down-arrow</kbd> to select the empty cells, same with <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> to select horizontally
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill with the formula

Answer (score 0):

highlight the cell(s). double click on the black box in the corner, and the formula gets filled down to the end of the data next to it.

In pictures:
hover here:
[image: black dot]
Your cursor should change to a black **+** when you are hovering over the dot.
After you double click, the formula will be filled down
[image]
this way will copy the formatting of that cell, but if you don't want that, you can click on the menu popup (lower left of filled area)
[image: menu popup]
and select fill without formatting